# Parameter using JSON to PHP server with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, ios, json, nsdictionary

I want to send NSDictionary or NSArray Parameter using JSON to PHP server with AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.url.com/"]];
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"key1":@"value1", @"key2",@"value2"};
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient postPath:@"some/path" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    ....

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    ....

}];
```